# Pyodbc won't connect to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, pyodbc

OperationalError:

> [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Encryption not supported on the client. (SQLDriverConnect);
>
> [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: The parameter is incorrect.
> [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection (21);
> [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.

On a different PC, with the same odbc driver-17 and SQL Server 2014, I am able to connect and query the tables.

My connection string looks like this:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(Trusted_Connection = 'yes',  
                      driver='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}',  
                      server='localhost',
                      database='db')
```

I have checked that it is a default instance `mssqlserver`.

Please suggest some way to fix this.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/031a0d1c-e35c-4a12-ab9b-bb402f4524a5/odbc-17-driver-encryption-not-supported-on-the-client-win-7-sp1?forum=sqldataaccess)?

Comment: @GordThompson - Yes Sir, thanks for the suggestion. I saw that, but in my case it's a pc for inventory & billings, and the client isn't ready to update the OS. Is it possible that columns are encrypted and therefore I am getting that encryption error?

Comment: @GordThompson: I'd like to explain to you what am I doing here. I want to create a data-emitter using Python that would send values of 3 fields(from the database I'm trying to connect to) to my server, if the inventory goes below the threshold. I am using Pyodbc to read the data, every 30 minutes, and trigger update to my server based on the threshold...but the database is not letting me to connect through that driver, and I'm stuck.

Comment: Well, seeing as how SQL Server 2008 is pretty old maybe you can get away with using an older version of the SQL Server ODBC driver, or possibly even FreeTDS ODBC.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll try with driver-11, and then notify you.

Comment: @GordThompson: In one of your answer, Pyodbc can't connect to database, you have used `Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}`. Should I try with that as well, my version for native client is 10 . Unfortunately, I'll get access to the computer 9 hrs later.

Comment: If you already have SQL Server Native Client 10.0 then you might as well try that one first. IIRC that was the version released for SQL Server 2008 anyway.

Comment: @GordThompson: Success!! I tried with `Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0}` and it got me connected, thanks a lot for your support.